# Change orientation of Facebook WebDialog in Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-orientation

I have an application that can be displayed in both Landscape orientations, using

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

in the manifest.

I have a button that opens a WebDialog of FacebookSDK to login. This dialog only displays in the normal Landscape layout, is there any way to set the orientation of this dialog sensor based?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify Orientation using for each activity within your android application.

Try out something like this in your XML:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.myapp.www.android.ui.activities.EditProfileActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
   />
```

different screen orientation types are as follows:

```
      android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "behind" |
                                 "landscape" | "portrait" |
                                 "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
                                 "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
                                 "userLandscape" | "userPortrait" |
                                 "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor" |
                                 "user" | "fullUser" | "locked"]
```